# (Sequelize) Why i can access the property inside dataValues without accessing dataValues property?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Why i can access the property inside dataValues without accessing dataValues property?

Example:

```
const data = await Product.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'name', 'price', 'stock', 'sku']
});

console.log(data);
```

Result of console.log(data):

```
[
  Product {
    dataValues: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Samsung Galaxy A53',
      price: 5000000,
      stock: 100,
      sku: 'SM001'
    },
    _previousDataValues: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Samsung Galaxy A53',
      price: 5000000,
      stock: 100,
      sku: 'SM001'
    },
    uniqno: 1,
    _changed: Set(0) {},
    _options: {
      isNewRecord: false,
      _schema: null,
      _schemaDelimiter: '',
      raw: true,
      attributes: [Array]
    },
    isNewRecord: false
  },
  Product {
    dataValues: {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Samsung Galaxy S22',
      price: 10000000,
      stock: 100,
      sku: 'SM002'
    },
    _previousDataValues: {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Samsung Galaxy S22',
      price: 10000000,
      stock: 100,
      sku: 'SM002'
    },
    uniqno: 1,
    _changed: Set(0) {},
    _options: {
      isNewRecord: false,
      _schema: null,
      _schemaDelimiter: '',
      raw: true,
      attributes: [Array]
    },
    isNewRecord: false
  }
]
```

I think if i want to get 'Samsung Galaxy A53', i must write a code like this:

```
console.log(data[0].dataValues.name) // it is works
```

But why i can get 'Samsung Galaxy A53' with a code like this?

```
console.log(data[0].name) // i can access directly to name property without using dataValues property
```

Comment: @Peterrabbit, but it is works bro, so i ask here because i'm confused why it is works...

Comment: Because that's what Sequelize does. [The documentation for `Model`](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js~model) tells you this as the very first thing.

Answer (score 0):

All Sequelize models are actually DAOs.
From the documentation:

```
A Model represents a table in the database. Instances of this class represent a database row.

Model instances operate with the concept of a dataValues property, which stores
the actual values represented by the instance.
By default, the values from dataValues can also be accessed directly from the Instance, that is:

instance.field
// is the same as
instance.get('field')
// is the same as
instance.getDataValue('field')

However, if getters and/or setters are defined for field they will be invoked,  
instead of returning the value from dataValues.
Accessing properties directly or using get is preferred for regular use,  
getDataValue should only be used for custom getters.
```

See [Model section](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js%7Emodel)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. But how is it possible in javascript rules? i'm just curious

Comment: What do you mean by JS rules? By default a model has getters/settirs for all fields and uses `dataValues` to get/set the underlying values. This prop is handful when you need to have custom getters and/or setters for some fields you might need to get the underlying value - and this is the moment when `dataValues` starts to play its role.

Comment: Hello sir, i'm just curious, is property 'field' is stored under prototypes? because i can't see property `field` in console.log(instance). I only see property 'dataValues', '_previousDataValues', etc. Thankyou before

Comment: It depends on how Sequelize model provides a text representation of itself. Maybe this answer helps you to get it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49461757/1376618

Comment: Thank you so much sir, your answer very helpful.  every time i use sequelize, that question is always on my mind. Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

You can't access the name by using `data[0].name`, because `data[0].name` *doesn't exist*.

As shown by your `console.log(...)`, the first element of your array of objects, `data[0]`, has these immediate properties:

- `dataValues`,
- `_previousDataValues`,
- `uniqno`,
- `_changed`,
- `_options`, and
- `isNewRecord`

The `name` is not a primary property, it's within the `dataValues`. That's why need to do `data[0].dataValues.name` or `data[0]["dataValues"]["name"]` to get it.

Comment: Except it does exist, as per [the documentation](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js~model). Don't (just) look at what console.log says: just because something doesn't show when console logging doesn't mean it won't resolve to something other than `undefined`.