# (node:71307) [DEP0079] DeprecationWarning

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Try to update MongoDB document Getting Deprecation Warning as

> (node:71307) [DEP0079] DeprecationWarning: Custom inspection function
>   on Objects via .inspect() is deprecated

Node version v10.5.0, 
db version v3.6.5, 
Mongoose version mongoose@4.1.12

```
Campground.findById(campgroundId, function(err, campground){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(campground.celebrity);
        Celebrity.create(celebrityData, function(err, celebrity){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                //save comment
                celebrity.save();
                campground.celebrity.push(celebrity);
                campground.save();
                console.log(celebrity);
                //req.flash('success', 'Created a comment!');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Please mention you node and mongoose version .

Comment: mongoose version ?

Comment: Mongoose version mongoose@4.1.12

Comment: This waning will come in mongoose for now. they will do work on this . for now its safe to go with this. Nothing to worry.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to not worry about this error this is mongoose warning . Actually Mongoose use inspect() to debug output . they will update it may be before node 12.x . For now it is safe to use this.

Nothing to worry.

Check this info.
https://nodejs.org/api/deprecations.html#deprecations_dep0079_custom_inspection_function_on_objects_via_inspect

> DEP0079: Custom inspection function on Objects via .inspect()# Type:
>   Runtime
>
> Using a property named inspect on an object to specify a custom
>   inspection function for util.inspect() is deprecated. Use
>   util.inspect.custom instead. For backward compatibility with Node.js
>   prior to version 6.4.0, both may be specified.

If you want more detail, see this . This is under progress. Warning will come in node 10

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6420

Comment: my mongoose version is 5.5.3 still I am getting error . even after adding this line

Answer (score 5):

In order to not get the deprecation message you can upgrade to mongoose version 5.2.10 or later according to this [Github mongoose issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6890) and the set the following at a proper location in code:

```
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true)
```

Comment: my mongoose version is 5.5.3 still I am getting error . even after adding this line

Answer (score 3):

upgrade to 5.2.10 and set

```
  mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to set it is...

```
mongoose.connect(
    "mongodb://<user>:<password>@<url>",
    { 
      useNewUrlParser: true, 
      useCreateIndex: true 
    }
  )
```

More information can be found here: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6890

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem, You have to use useNewUrlParser and useCreateIndex. See the code below.

```
mongoose.connect(
 config.databaseUrl,
 { 
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useCreateIndex: true 
 }
)
```

Or

```
mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);    
mongoose.connect(
    config.databaseUrl,
    { 
        useNewUrlParser: true
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add the options `useCreateIndex` to your connect method

```
mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Totally random but at least it's not a copycat answer: I was getting this deprecation warning (and unexpected behavior) when I accidentally used `Model.find()` instead of `Model.findOne()`

So my erroneous code looked like this

```
User.find(query)
.then(user => {
  console.log(user.emailSettings.confirmToken)
})
```

...with an ordinary object/array, this would fail with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'confirmToken' of undefined` but with an mongo document array apparently it does this inspecty thing and now gives this deprecation warning.

Answer (score 1):

**I want to add to this thread that it may also have to do with other dependencies.**

For instance, nothing I updated or set for NodeJS, MongoDB or Mongoose were the issue - however - my problem was that `connect-mongodb-session` had been updated and starting slinging the same error. The solution, in this case, was to simply rollback the version of `connect-mongodb-session` from version `2.3.0` to `2.2.0`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.CONNECTION_MONGO, {
useNewUrlParser: true,
useUnifiedTopology: true,
useCreateIndex: true,
useFindAndModify: false,
})
.then(() => {
console.log("Database connected...");
})
.catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.