# Override String Representation of an Array in JavaScript for Console Log

Tags: javascript, tostring, console.log

I was hoping I could override what is displayed by console.log. I was assuming the below:

```
const arr = ['ben', 'john', 'amy']; 
Array.prototype.toString = function(){return 'alex';}
console.log(arr); // hoping this could result in 'alex' being printed to the screen. Prints the array.
```

I was hoping I could make the array print my 'alex' override to the screen but it looks like that is not how console.log works. The toString function must not be was is used to determine the log. Does anyone know how this is determined or if it can be overridden?

Comment: `console.log` doesn't cast its argument to a string, but does some implementation-specific thing. Which `console` implementation are you using? Does your script run in a browser (which?), in nodejs, or somewhere else?

Comment: I tried in chrome and node

Comment: It's not possible to change the inspector display of the Chrome debugger. For the rest, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24902061/is-there-an-repr-equivalent-for-javascript