# Convert object values to string when values are: undefined, null or boolean

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this object:

```
const obj = {
 key1: false,
 key2: "",
 key3: undefined,
 key4: null
}
```

Now, I want to use Object.values(obj) so I will get an array of values. But false, undefined & null return as an empty string or in the false case it returns 1 or 0.

So I want to convert the object values to strings.

What will be the best way to do so?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(obj)` will get you most of the way there, but `key3: undefined` is being treated as if it had never been defined at all.

Comment: _"But false, undefined & null return as an empty string or in the false case it returns 1 or 0"_ - Nope, that's not how `Object.values()` works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an \_\_repr\_\_ equivalent for javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24902061/is-there-an-repr-equivalent-for-javascript)

Comment: use `JSON.stringify`

Comment: You can map the values to strings, `Object.values(obj).map(String)` if you want an array of strings...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try out [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
const result = Object
                .values({
                   key1: false,
                   key2: "",
                   key3: undefined,
                   key4: null
                })
                .map(v => `${v}`)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I was thinking `Object.values(obj).map(el => el?el:`${el}`)`

Comment: true that is right.

Comment: @Yevgen Gorbunkov It works but some of the object values can be objects or array. So I wrote this: Object.values(obj).map(v => !v ? `${v}`: v);   But if one of the values will be 'True' it wont go through

Comment: @Yevgen Gorbunkov Solved it with this one: Object.values(item).map(v => !v ? `${v}`: v===true ? `${v}`: v);