# How to print literal representation of a string in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, representation

In my program there is a REPL loop that occassionaly need to print to the console a string representation of the given string variable.
For example, suppose that we have have a string variable *str* defined somewhere in the program:

```
var str = "two\nlines";
```

I would like to have a print function (call it, for example, **printRepr**) that print to the console the string representation of str:

```
> printRepr(str);
"two\nlines"
```

I cannot find such a function in the documentation. Is there an easy way to get this behavior?

Note: I know that the Node.js REPL have this behavior, but i need a function that I would use in my program to print literal representation of any string. Of course, I cannot use **console.log()** because in that case I'd get this:

```
> console.log(str);
two
lines
```

Comment: 'one \n two line'

Comment: Ok, I know that Node.js repl have this behavior, but i need the same in my program.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` should do.

Comment: Bergi, Great! This is the best answer! :)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24902061/is-there-an-repr-equivalent-for-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [util.inspect](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/how-to-use-util-inspect/)

```
const util = require('util');
const str = "two\nlines";
console.log(util.inspect(str));
```

Alternatively use [String.raw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) or [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) (depending on your needs)

this will work in a browser too

```js
console.log(String.raw`two\nlines`);

const str = `two\nlines`;
console.log(JSON.stringify(str))
```

Comment: mplungjan: can I use String.raw to print the string in variable str? It seems that it's not possible. :(

Comment: JSON.stringify is the best answer (doesn't require any additional library)