# Cannot succesfully keep hexadecimal text in JS/TS

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, hex

I have the following hexadecimal string:

```
const data = '\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x90\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00{\x14\xaeG\xe1zt?\xe9\x86/\xb25\x0e&@\b\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

No matter what I do, the printed output is `{.Gazt?i/25&   d` with a lot of spaces.
I really some help to keep it as is, can anyone help me out please?

Comment: You need to mask the backslashes: `\\x03\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x05\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x02\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x90\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x80\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x03\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00{\\x14\\xaeG\\xe1zt?\\xe9\\x86/\\xb25\\x0e&@\\b\\x00\\x00\\x00d\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00`

Comment: Didn't steal your answer btw. Just was responding from a smartphone and took a few minutes to enter all the backslashes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an \_\_repr\_\_ equivalent for javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24902061/is-there-an-repr-equivalent-for-javascript)

Comment: Not sure the link helps, but thanks

Answer (score 1):

To keep it as it is, use **double backslashes**.

like de code below:

```
const data = '\\x03\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x05\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x02\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x90\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x80\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x03\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00{\\x14\\xaeG\\xe1zt?\\xe9\\x86/\\xb25\\x0e&@\\b\\x00\\x00\\x00d\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'
```

When you use just one backslash Javascript understand you want the ASCII representation of the Hex number you're passing to them *that's why you have a bunch of whitespaces because \x00 is a space, or nothing at all*.

Comment: Okay, but what if I get this from an async function? how can I force the response to contain to mask? is there package/function to do this?

Comment: Yeah, sure. You can do this doing something like:
string.replace('/', '//'); But I will try this first.

Comment: That doesn't work... I did the following:
```
const data = "\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x90\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00{\x14\xaeG\xe1zt?\xe9\x86/\xb25\x0e&@\b\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00";
const replaced = data.replace(/\//g, "\\");
console.log(replaced)
```
The output is still {®Gázt?é\²5&   d

Comment: Any solution? I am still stuck here

Answer (score 0):

Just escape the backslashes. `'x03\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x05\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x02\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x90\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x80\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x03\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00{\\x14\\xaeG\\xe1zt?\\xe9\\x86\/\\xb25\\x0e&@\\b\\x00\\x00\\x00d\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'`