# Control the output of a console.log when printing an object that extends the string class JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects, console.log

I have a class that expands the string class and I was wondering if you could control the output if you were to try to print the object,

Here is my class:

```js
class betterString extends String {
  constructor() {
    super("Test")
    this.RealString = "test 2"
  }
  func() {
    return "Useless Value"
  }
}
```

and if I initialize the object and try to print it, this is the output:

```js
[String (betterString): 'Test'] { RealString: 'test 2' }
```

is there a way to make a console.log output "Test" instead of that mess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26698403/18174155) answers what I wanted to do

it uses the built in module known as `util` and it can set the default print value for an object

```js
const util = require('util');

class MyClass {
  constructor(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }
  [util.inspect.custom]() {
    return `a is ${this.a} and b is ${this.b}`;
  }
}

const my_object = new MyClass(1, 2);
console.log(util.inspect(my_object));
console.log(my_object);
```

[Ciro Santilli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/895245/ciro-santilli-ourbigbook-com) was the person to originally answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Since you are extending `String`, you will have access to all the methods in the prototype chain. [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) is a method coming from the `Object.prototype`. It will give you the string representation of your object.

```js
class BetterString extends String {
  constructor() {
    super("Test")
    this.RealString = "test 2"
  }
  func() {
    return "Useless Value"
  }
}

const obj = new BetterString();
console.log(obj.toString());
```

Comment: `toString` is inherited from `String.prototype`, not from `Object.prototype`

Comment: `toString()` is not always used when printing to console, e.g. not for functions.